# Is shared library local variable thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-libraries

I'm developing a multi-threaded application which application which will access a shared library, now i see that the shared library doesn't contain any global variable, so does it mean that the library is thread safe? for example.

I'm calling function `func()` from various threads to a shared library like:

thread 1 -> func()

thread 2 -> func()

...

thread N ->func()

and the func() is defined as below,

```
void func(){
    int var;
    func2(&var);
}
```

In this cases, will it be thread safe?

Comment: If you're asking will `var` be independent for each thread, yes. It is an automatic variable.  Whether the rest of `func2` is "thread-safe" is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The usage that you are showing is thread-safe, because invocations of `func` from each thread will have their own copy of the variable `var`.

This is not a guarantee, though, for several reasons:

- Library needs to be careful about its use of `static` variables as well. If you replace `int var` with `static int var`, `func` would not longer be thread-safe
- You need to be careful about calling the library. If the same pattern that you show is present in your code, i.e. if your code shares a local variable among threads, the code would not be thread-safe.
- The library may use functions that are not thread-safe, such as `strtok`. Using these functions makes your library not thread-safe.

Comment: yeah will take care of it, my only concern is that the shared libraries will be loaded in the common memory and if the threads tries to access it, will it be safe. thanks for your response.

Comment: you shouldn't mess around with the common memory - just stick to malloc and friends, and you'll be finde. then there shouldn't be a problem with accessing another thread's stack 'by accident'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code in question will execute in the context of each thread, and the local automatic variable will typically be stored on each thread's stack.